# How to iterate over binary masks of long long?

Tags: c++, binary

How to iterate over unique (`...000010000...`) binary masks of `long long`? 
I meant over masks like `0001, 0010, 0100, 1000`

Comment: What does it mean to iterate a binary mask?

Comment: Just do a `for` loop over all the possible `long long` values and use each as a mask, maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean each mask with a single bit set:

```
for (unsigned long long mask = 1; mask != 0; mask <<= 1) {
    // Do something with mask
}
```

Note that you must use `unsigned` in order to have defined behaviour when the shift overflows.

I assume you don't mean every possible mask value; it would take a very long time to iterate through all of them.